# Ruby - Calling a method from a child object

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and trying to determine how I can call a class from a child object. Something like the below; however when I try it, I get an error saying "undefined local variable or method `me'"

```
class my_object < Object
    attr_accessor :me

    def initialize(attributes ={})
    end


    def setvalue(passed_value)
      @passed_value = passed_value.to_s
    end 

    def search(passed_value) 
      @passed_value.include?(passed_value)
    end

   end

   def getMe
    me_too = my_object.new
    me_too.me = "test"
    me_too.me.search("test")

   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
instance.class
```

will give you a reference to the class

Answer (score 0):

This works:
But your code had multiple errors.

```
class MY
    attr_accessor :me

    def initialize(attributes ={})
    end


    def setvalue(passed_value)
      passed_value = passed_value.to_s
    end

    def search(passed_value)
      passed_value.include?(passed_value)
    end


   def getMe
    me_too = MY.new
    me_too.me = "test"
    me_too.search("test")

   end
end

my = MY.new
my.getMe
```

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to explicity extend Object, everything extends Object in ruby.
- Your class name needs to start with a capital letter.

  class MyObject
      attr_accessor :me

  end

  me_too = MyObject.new
  me_too.me = "test"

in console

```
me_too => #<MyObject:0x106b2e420 @me="test">
```

Check out some introductory ruby tutorials maybe http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/